# Summation of sines with limits and a variable?

Tags: matlab

I need help to add a function, from `1` to `10`, using MATLAB.  The function is (`(1/n)*sin(n*pi*x)`) where `n` goes from `1` to `10` and `x` stays as a variable. Ultimately I want to have a summation of ten sines (i.e `K1*sin(pi*x)+K2*sin(2*pi*x)+k3*sin(3*pi*x)+...`etc) where `k` is a constant. I would really appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Edit: Thanks to everyone who helped with my problem However I should have been more specific when asking my question. After getting the summation, I want to plot the sine series. I tried doing this but I kept getting an error saying that "conversion from sym to double is not possible" Now I tried doing a for loop to get my graph. My code is as follows:

```
 n = 0:10;
while i <= n
    for i = 1:length(n);
        T = (1/n(i))*sin(n(i)*pi*x);
    end
      i = 1+i;
      max = sum(T);
   end
```

plot(x,max,'black')

However this doesn't work. I don't think that this is the proper way to get the sum of a double. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me again. Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are trying to sum the **multivariable** expression. In your case, you have two variables n and x. You want to sum the expression from n = 1 to 10 keeping x as a variable. You can do this in MATLAB by using `symsum` function, whose syntax is

```
symsum(expr,var,a,b)
```

*Where expression expr defines the terms of a series, with respect to the symbolic variable var. The value of the variable var changes from a to b. If you do not specify the variable, symsum uses the default variable determined by symvar. If expr is a constant, then the default variable is x.*

So in your case

```
expr = (1/n*sin(n*pi*x)
var = n
a = 1
b = 10
```

The simple code would be

```
>>syms n x
>>F = symsum ((1/sym('n'))*sin(sym('n')*pi*x), n, 1, 10)
```

**Answer to Edit**: MATLAB cannot convert the sys variable to double. You can instead substitute the value of sym variable with variable from MATLAB workspace. For example you can plot the above function for the range 0 to 10 by using following command.

```
>> x = 0:0.1:10;
>> plot(x, subs(F))
```

Comment: @user3217657 if you got answer then accept it. This may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to exploit MATLAB's vector nature.

For one-off shots:

```
>> f = @(n,x) sin((1:n)*pi*x) * (1./(1:n).');
>> f(200, 0.5)
ans =
    7.828982258896381e-001
```

To be able to evaluate `f(n,x)` with vector/matrix input `x`:

```
>> f = @(n,x) reshape( sin( bsxfun(@times, (1:n)*pi, x(:)) ) * (1./(1:n).'), size(x) );
>> f(15,rand(2))
ans =
    5.077194963950054e-001    2.660834723822258e-001
    1.416130930552744e+000    1.012255979042172e-001
```

Replace `(1./(1:n).')` by `[K1 K2 K3 ...].'` when you want to use other constants than `1/n`.